Duplicate HTTP PATCH Requests to Express Server from React Client Despite Single Axios Call
I'm encountering a perplexing issue in my React + Node.js + Express application, where my backend receives duplicate PATCH requests for a single operation initiated from the client. This behavior persists despite thorough checks confirming only one request being made from the client side.
Context:
My React component, SyncWorker, is designed to sync data with a backend upon detecting an online status. It uses Dexie for IndexedDB operations and Axios for HTTP requests. Despite measures to prevent duplicate operations, the backend logs indicate two PATCH requests being received in quick succession for a single sync operation.
Client-Side Implementation:
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useLiveQuery } from "dexie-react-hooks";
import axios from "axios";
import { DeviceConfiguration, db } from "../../db";
import uploadFile from "../helpers/uploadFile";
import useFirebase from "../hooks/useFirebase";
import { base64ToFile } from "../helpers/base64ToFile";

function SyncWorker() {
  const queryResults = useLiveQuery(() => db.configurations.toArray(), []);
  const { storage } = useFirebase();
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(navigator.onLine);
  const [isSyncing, setIsSyncing] = useState(false);

  const processingIdsRef = useRef<Set<number>>(new Set());

  const syncItems = useCallback(
    async (unsynced: DeviceConfiguration[]) => {
      setIsSyncing(true);

      for (const item of unsynced) {
        if (processingIdsRef.current.has(item.id!)) continue;

        processingIdsRef.current.add(item.id!);
        console.log(
          `${new Date().toISOString()} - Starting sync for item with ID: ${
            item.id
          }`
        );
        const imageName = `${item.position_identifier}_${
          item.serial_number
        }_${new Date().toISOString()}`;
        const imageAsFile = base64ToFile(item.photo, imageName);

        try {
          const imageUrl = await uploadFile(
            storage!,
            imageAsFile,
            `jobs/${item.ongoing_job_id}/${item.position_identifier}`,
            imageAsFile.name
          );

          const response = await axios.patch(
            `${
              import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_SERVER_BASE_URL
            }/ongoing-jobs/configure-device`,
            {
              ongoing_job_id: item.ongoing_job_id,
              type: item.type,
              image_url: imageUrl,
              position_identifier: item.position_identifier,
              serial_number: item.serial_number,
            }
          );
          console.log(response.data);

          await db.configurations.update(item.id!, { synced: true });
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("Failed to update monitor: ", err);
        } finally {
          processingIdsRef.current.delete(item.id!);
        }
      }

      setIsSyncing(false); // Mark as syncing finished
    },
    [storage]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const goOnline = () => setIsOnline(true);
    const goOffline = () => setIsOnline(false);

    window.addEventListener("online", goOnline);
    window.addEventListener("offline", goOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("online", goOnline);
      window.removeEventListener("offline", goOffline);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!queryResults || !isOnline || isSyncing) return;

    const unsynced = queryResults.filter((item) => !item.synced);
    if (unsynced.length > 0) {
      console.log(
        `${new Date().toISOString()} - SyncWorker useEffect triggered for ${
          unsynced.length
        } items`
      );

      syncItems(unsynced).catch(console.error);
    }
  }, [queryResults, isOnline, isSyncing, syncItems]);

  return null;
}

export default SyncWorker;

Server-Side Code Snippet:
Here's a simplified version of my Express setup and the relevant route handler:
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
require("./mongoose");

import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import ongoingJobsRouter from "./routers/ongoing-jobs";

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

app.set("socketio", io);
app.use(ongoingJobsRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(
    `*********************************************************************** SERVER IS RUNNING ON PORT ${PORT}***********************************************************************`
  );
});

Then this is the route handler
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.patch("/ongoing-jobs/configure-device", async (req, res) => {
  // Handler logic here
  console.log("Configuring device for: ", req.body.position_identifier);
  res.status(200).send("Configured device");
});

module.exports = router;

Issue:
The server logs two PATCH requests for a single operation from the client, verified by backend logs and client-side observations.
Server-side log at the beginning of my route handler prints twice for a single sync operation initiation from the client. Th full rout inserts an item into an array, and when executed in full (instead of retuning immediately after the log) two items are added rather than one.
Client-side, I've confirmed through the Network tab and console logs that only one request is made per item. Additional debugging, including logging the response from the server and reviewing the Network tab multiple times, supports this.
Measures taken:
Confirmed React Strict Mode is disabled, and used a Set to track processing items by ID to prevent reprocessing.
Question:
Given the detailed checks and the certainty that only one request is made from the client side, what could be causing the server to register two requests?
I've inspected middleware, checked for accidental retries, and confirmed the absence of any unusual network activity that could explain this behavior. Any insights or suggestions on potential causes or debugging strategies would be greatly appreciated.
